# How can I convert my df of prices into a df of returns on 100 based

Tags: r, price, performanceanalytics

I want to calculate returns from my dataframe and generate a new df where my values are on based 100.

Example:

```py
Date         Ubam US Corporate
18/02/2014   185.31
19/02/2014   185.17  
20/02/2014   185.06
Date         Ubam US Corporate
18/02/2014   100
19/02/2014   99.9992 <- 100+(1*((185.17/185.31)-1))
20/02/2014   99.9987
```

This is my df

https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAFv-jeRgpk4_DpH7R4eCajykisZs0_fuJL8FP08AAUZQxXxou90

Is there a function to calculate this automatically?

Thank you

Comment: Python, pandas is it?

Comment: I am using Rstudio

Comment: Gotcha, then please remember whenever you post a question on so - always indicate the technology it concerns in your tags. That's number one tag, that you should put ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c('18/02/2014','19/02/2014','20/02/2014'), Ubam = c(185.31, 185.17, 185.06))
```

you can first create a vector of price changes, with 100 as the first entry:

```
price_changes <- c(100, tail(df[, 'Ubam'], -1) / head(df[, 'Ubam'], -1) - 1)
```

Then you can do a cumulative sum to create the rebased price index as a new column in `df`:

```
df$rebased_index <- cumsum(price_changes)
df
#output
    Date       Ubam rebased_index
1 18/02/2014 185.31     100.00000
2 19/02/2014 185.17      99.99924
3 20/02/2014 185.06      99.9986
```

Comment: Hi, my df is a df of n rows from 18/02/2014 to 15/01/2020 an n columns. What I did is: VLPFI.rent <-Return.calculate(VLPFI, method = c("discrete")) but now I dont know to generate a df with rebased price.